# Music21: Strip empty data at end of written midi file

Tags: python, music21

I am writing a simple midi file using music21:

```
import music21

stream = music21.stream.Stream()
n = music21.note.Note(60)
n.duration.type = 'half'
stream.insert(0, n)
stream.write('midi', 'out.midi')
```

This plays middle c for half a measure. However, the resulting file contains empty space for the remainder of that measure:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that trailing "whitespace"?

Comment: A hack is to add the necessary whitespace to the start of the midi file instead, so that the file ends when the last note ends. E.g. in the case above, `stream.insert(0, n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version from PyPI (7.1.0) seems to always add one quarter note of silence at the end. This can be changed by setting `music21.defaults.ticksAtStart`, despite its name. The units are MIDI ticks defined by `music21.defaults.ticksPerQuarter`. The default value of both is 1024.

Be aware that some MIDI players will stop synthesizing when the file ends, so the sound will stop dead when the last note is released instead of dying away if there is no padding.

Also, some players may pad to a measure boundary no matter what you do. There is no way to encode a pickup measure in MIDI, other than inserting rests.

Comment: Great analysis! Yes, since v.5 getEndEvents() will add the start delay to the end also, for convenience reasons you describe. Another workaround is to override getEndEvents(). An enhancement could be to expose addEndDelay as a kwarg just like addStartDelay (and allow both kwargs to be passed to show() and write())